# Different files being generated for the ng build in angular 8 as compared to the previous version of angular 5/6/7

Tags: angular

This is my first time working on angular web components.
I tried many online tutorial and even video tutorials, I see that the examples discussed in the tutorial are of the angular 5/6/7 versions but can't find example or tutorial for angular 8.

Like on `npm run build` in Angular 5/6/7 versions it would generate this files :

```
"./dist/my-app/runtime.js",
"./dist/my-app/polyfills.js",
"./dist/my-app/scripts.js",
"./dist/my-app/main.js"
```

but in Angular 8 it generates this files:

```
"./dist/my-app/runtime-es2015.js",
"./dist/my-app/runtime-es2015.js",
"./dist/my-app/polyfills-es2015.js",
"./dist/my-app/polyfills-es5.js",
"./dist/my-app/scripts.js",
"./dist/my-app/main-es5.js"
"./dist/my-app/main-es2015.js"
```

I tried these tutorials
[Web Components with angular](https://medium.com/@IMM9O/web-components-with-angular-d0205c9db08f)

[Web Components using Angular — Are you sure?](https://codeburst.io/web-components-using-angular-are-you-sure-5a8c7089a51c)

I am stuck on this part

> create a script to eject our web component as a single file

because the files don't match

Comment: Did you do the `ng build --prod --output-hashing=none` step? Then it's just that `build-element.js` step, but with different files...

Comment: please  read official angular doc : https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: @Cerbrus, Yes I did I am getting files with -es5 and -es2015 .js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to differential loading.  A new feature introduced in angular 8 to load app in all browsers. In Angular 8 the file browserlist have to be in project root folder. Following entries were needed on project to disable differential loading and which helps to match files

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11
not samsung 4
not android 4.4.3-4.4.4
not last 2 ie_mob versions
not last 2 op_mini versions
not last 2 op_mob versions
not last 2 baidu versions
not last 2 kaios versions
not last 2 and_uc versions
not last 2 and_qq versions
not last 2 edge versions
not chrome 49
```

Comment: `not IE 9-11` Lucky you.

Comment: Excuse me? Don't blame me for that downvote that anyone could've cast @KamleshKatpara.